# Why do Rust lifetimes matter when I move values into a spawned Tokio task?

Tags: rust, ownership, rust-tokio, lifetime-scoping

I'm trying to create a struct that will manage a Tokio task with one `tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender` that sends input to the task, one `tokio::sync::mpsc::Receiver` that receives output from the task, and a handle that I can join at the end.

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc;
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;

// A type that implements BlockFunctionality consumes instances of T and
// produces either Ok(Some(U)) if an output is ready, Ok(None) if an output
// is not ready, or an Err(_) if the operation fails
pub trait BlockFunctionality<T, U> {
    fn apply(&mut self, input: T) -> Result<Option<U>, &'static str>;
}

pub struct Block<T, U> {
    pub tx_input: mpsc::Sender<T>,
    pub rx_output: mpsc::Receiver<U>,
    pub handle: JoinHandle<Result<(), &'static str>>,
}

impl<T: Send, U: Send> Block<T, U> {
    pub fn from<B: BlockFunctionality<T, U> + Send>(b: B) -> Self {
        let (tx_input, mut rx_input) = mpsc::channel(10);
        let (mut tx_output, rx_output) = mpsc::channel(10);

        let handle: JoinHandle<Result<(), &'static str>> = tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut owned_b = b;

            while let Some(t) = rx_input.recv().await {
                match owned_b.apply(t)? {
                    Some(u) => tx_output
                        .send(u)
                        .await
                        .map_err(|_| "Unable to send output")?,
                    None => (),
                }
            }

            Ok(())
        });

        Block {
            tx_input,
            rx_output,
            handle,
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get this error for `B` and a similar one for the other two type parameters:

```
   |
22 |     pub fn from<B: BlockFunctionality<T, U> + Send>(b:B) -> Self {
   |                 -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `B: 'static +`
...
27 |         let handle:JoinHandle<Result<(), &'static str>> = tokio::spawn(async move {
   |                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `impl std::future::Future` will meet its required lifetime bounds
```

I'm having a hard time understanding where the problem is with lifetimes.  The way I understand it, lifetime problems usually come from references that don't live long enough, but I'm moving values, not using references.  I move `b`, `rx_input`, and `tx_output` into the closure and I keep `tx_input`, `rx_output`, and `handle` in the calling scope.  Does anyone know how to satisfy the compiler in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those *values* may be references or contain references. Reference types are valid types: `B` could be `&'a str`. Or `B` could be `SomeType<'a>`, a type with a lifetime parameter, that itself contains a `&'a str`.

To say that `B: 'static` means that all lifetime parameters of `B` outlive `'static` ([ref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds)). For example, types which own their own data and thus have no lifetime parameters (e.g. `String`) satisfy this bound. But `&'static str` also satisfies the bound.

Because `tokio::spawn` creates something whose lifetime is not statically scoped, it [requires a `'static` argument](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.1/tokio/fn.spawn.html).

So to satisfy the compiler, add the `'static` bounds:

```
impl<T: 'static + Send, U: 'static + Send> Block<T, U> {
    pub fn from<B: 'static + BlockFunctionality<T, U> + Send>(b:B) -> Self {
```

Comment: That did it!  I didn't realize that owned values were considered `'static`.